# NullPointer ao solicitar execução - ExtentReport

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Estou com dificuldade em utilizar a api do extent. A maneira como desenvolvi meu projeto, está impedindo que consiga tirar os prints.
Criei uma classe DriveFactory que instancio o driver e interajo com os elementos, chamando nas classes steps. Segue abaixo:

public class DriverFactory {

```
private static WebDriver driver;
private static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
private static ExtentReports extentReport;
private static ExtentTest extentTest;
```

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeCenario(Scenario cenario){

```
    if(driver == null) {


        switch (Propriedades.browser) {
            case FIREFOX: 
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/portal/Documents/Drivers/geckodriver");    
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
                    ; break;
            case CHROME: 
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/portal/Documents/Drivers/chromedriver");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                if(extentReport == null) {
                    extentReport = new ExtentReports();
                    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("src/test/resources/htmlReporter.html");
                    extentReport.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
                }

                extentTest = extentReport.createTest (cenario.getId());


                break;
            case EDGE: 
                driver = new EdgeDriver(); break;
            case IE:
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            break;
        }
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1800, 900)); 

    }

}


public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

@After
public void afterCenario(Scenario cenario) {
    extentTest.log(Status.PASS, "Cenario "+ cenario.getName()+ " executado com sucesso");
    extentReport.flush();

}

public static void killDriver(){
    if(driver != null) {
        extentReport.flush();
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
}


public static ExtentTest getExtentTest() {
    return extentTest;
}
```

}

**Trecho da classe Steps**

Classe Steps 
public class SolicitarAssinaturaAutenticadoSteps {

```
HomePage home = PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), HomePage.class);
NavBarPage nav= PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), NavBarPage.class);
LoginPage login =PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), LoginPage.class);
AssinePage assine = PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), AssinePage.class);
LoginGooglePage lGoogle = PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), LoginGooglePage.class);
LoginFacebookPage lFacebook = PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), LoginFacebookPage.class);


@Given("^que o usuario está na pagina inicial do Estadão$")
public void que_o_usuario_está_na_pagina_inicial_do_Estadão() throws Throwable {
    home.acessarHomePage();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    home.fecharPropaganda();
    home.fecharPush();
}

@Given("^realiza login$")
public void realiza_login() throws Throwable {
    nav.cliqueEntrar();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    login.setUsuario("j@gmail.com");
    login.setSenha("");
    login.entrar();

}

@Given("^realiza login via Google$")
public void realiza_login_via_Google() throws Throwable {
    nav.cliqueEntrar();
    login.clickBotaoEntrarGoogle();
    lGoogle.setEmail("@gmail.com");
    lGoogle.clickProximo();
    lGoogle.setSenha("");
```

O problema é que na classe steps, eu dou um PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), HomePage.class); e coloco na chamada a classe DriverFactory, mas mesmo colocando um @Before no metodo beforeCenario na classe DriverFactoru para que ele seja executado antes do metodo getDriver, ele nao reconhece e aparece nullPointer. Como posso resolver isso?